# Python: How do I 'demote' a column header to be a row and rename column headers (without replacing the original column headers)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

and as you can see the column headers "Arts & Social Sciences 1, 470, 905, 1375" is supposed to be a row itself and I want to set more appropriate column headers like "course, male, female, total".

In essence, I want to 'push' my current column headers down as a row of data, and set new column headers.
How do I do that?

I want my dataframe to look like this:

| Faculty | Male | Female | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arts & Social Sciences 1 | 470 | 905 | 1375 |
| Arts & Social Sciences 2 | 438 | 1085 | 1523 |

... and so on

---EDIT---

Thanks for the responses!
I should have given more information and stated that I'm not reading this dataframe in using pandas but I'm reading it from a PDF using the `tabula` library with the tabula.read_pdf() function, and the dataframes come out like this. Any ideas?

Comment: When you read the frame set header to none: `df = pd.read_csv(file.csv, header=None)` then assign the new columns: `df.columns = ['Faculty', 'Male', . . .]`

Comment: How are you reading this dataframe in? You may need to supply column names. If it's `pd.read_csv(..., names=["Faculty", "Male", "Female", "Total"])` should work

Comment: ---EDIT---

Thanks for the responses! I should have given more information and stated that I'm not reading this dataframe in using pandas but I'm reading it from a PDF using the tabula library with the tabula.read_pdf() function, and the dataframes come out like this. Any ideas?

Comment: @BernardC in the [tabula docs](https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html#tabula.io.read_pdf) it states you can use `pandas_options={"names": ["Faculty", "Male", "Female", "Total"])}` if your reading a single table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, if you are reading `CSV` file, you can pass the column  names:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(filePath, names=["Faculty", "Male", "Female", "Total"])
```

But if you already have the dataframe, you can add the columns to index at -1, then you can reset the index, you can also sort the index if needed.:

```py
df.loc[-1] = df.columns.to_list() 
df = df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = ['Faculty', 'Male', 'Female', 'Totals']
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's somehow too late for re-reading the data, you can stack the columns' values and the current values together and generate a new dataframe with your column names passed:

```
import numpy as np

all_values = np.row_stack((df.columns, df.to_numpy()))
new_df = pd.DataFrame(all_values, columns=["Faculty", "Male", "Female", "Total"])
```

---

[`tabula.read_pdf`](https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html#tabula.io.read_pdf) also seems to support pandas options, so:

```
col_names = ["Faculty", "Male", "Female", "Total"]
tabula.read_pdf(path,
                pandas_options=dict(header=None, names=col_names))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really useful but unfortunately the tables from the PDF are being read with 4 & 5 columns inconsistently. Not the best but I can work with that!